# mySQL - How to create a table with amount of columns depending on index (integer) in another table

Tags: mysql, create-table

I have a table and every time a row is added to this table a new table should be created with an amount of columns depending on an entry of the first table.

So more specific: I have the table "test" with columns "ID", "name" and "number". "number" is an integer number for each row. 
I want that every time, a row is added to the table "test" a new table is created with the tablename "numbersX", where X is test.id and with columns "time", "number1", "number2", "number3", ..., "numberZ", where Z = test.number.

This is an example for the test table:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test;
CREATE TABLE test (
   id INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT,
   name NVARCHAR(45),
   number INT(11),
   PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
INSERT INTO test
    VALUES (DEFAULT, 'Fred', 4),
           (DEFAULT, 'Lucy', 1),
           (DEFAULT, 'Jenny', 12)
    ;
```

Unfortunately I am very new to mySQL and have no idea, how to do it. 
I now how to create a new table with entries from another table, but i can't find anything about new tables with columns depending on an index in another table.

Later I want to use a trigger for the automatization.

The resulting tables for the three entries above should look like these:

```
CREATE TABLE numbers1 (
    time DATETIME,
    number1 INT(11),
    number2 INT(11),
    number3 INT(11),
    number4 INT(11),
    PRIMARY KEY (time)
    );

CREATE TABLE numbers2 (
    time DATETIME,
    number1 INT(11),
    PRIMARY KEY (time)
    );

CREATE TABLE numbers3 (
    time DATETIME,
    number1 INT(11),
    number2 INT(11),
    number3 INT(11),
    number4 INT(11),
    number5 INT(11),
    number6 INT(11),
    number7 INT(11),
    number8 INT(11),
    number9 INT(11),
    number10 INT(11),
    number11 INT(11),
    number12 INT(11),
    PRIMARY KEY (time)
    );
```

Any idea? Maybe just a hint, if it is possible and if yes, where I should have a closer look in the SQL field?!

**UPDATE(02/08/2019)**

Let me try to explain it again. 
The table "test" gives me, first column: an ID, second column: the name of, let's say a measuring station and third column: a number, which is the amount of temperature sensors at this measuring station.
Each Sensor at each station saves the temperature every 15 minutes. I need a table where i save all these values (including the measured temperatures for the last 20 years!) corresponding to the time recorded ("timestamp"). And it is possible, that at certain points there will come new measuring stations, which should be also recorded.

If I use your suggestion now, Progman, I would have one huge table, where the composition of timestamp (a DATETIME) and the id from "test" table are my PK. The other columns would be "sensor1", "sensor2", "sensor3", ... For some measuring stations I only have one sensor, there would be only entries in the first three columns (timestamp, test.id, sensor1). For another station I have 3 sonsors and for a third one there are 100 sensors. So I would have 100 "sensor-columns", but for the first case, 99 of these sensor columns are just NULL. Does this takes any performance in doing queries, calculations and in general the space it takes to save this table?

Additional I have a lot of measuring stations. Thus means I have a row for each timestamp times the number of stations (assuming they started measuring all at the same day). So for 20 years, one entry every 15 minutes, for lets say 500 stations... that's over 70 Million rows...
And this is still a simplified version of what I want to do. So there are even more columns (different sensor types and stuff).
As I said, I am new to SQL (and coding in general). Do you think that's not too much for one table, will still be fast?

I thought it would be better to create an own table for every measuring station. But I am glad to hear if I am wrong! Just want to make sure you know, what exactly is my intention!

Answer (score 0):

That is not how you should do it. You usually don't create tables on-the-fly. Also, your column names shouldn't have any index like "number8". Such tables are very difficult to work with and the SQL queries are getting very complicated.

Instead, you should create only one additional table for the numbers. This table has a foreign key to the row in your `test` table. This way you can find the rows in the `numbers` table which belong to one row in the `test` table. Depending on what you want to save, the new table might look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE numbers (
   id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
   testId INT NOT NULL,
   numberIndex INT,
   numberValue INT,

   PRIMARY KEY (id),
   FOREIGN KEY FK_numbers_testId(testId) REFERENCES test(id)
);
```

You can use these tables like this:

```
INSERT INTO
    test(name, number)
VALUES
    ('Fred', 4);


/* retrieve Id of generated row here based on the API/code you are using */


INSERT INTO
    numbers(testId, numberIndex, numberValue)
VALUES
    (theGeneratedId, 1, 42),
    (theGeneratedId, 2, 15),
    (theGeneratedId, 3, -300),
    (theGeneratedId, 4, 7);
```

Comment: Hi Progman,
Thank you. That's exactly the way I wanted to do it first.
The thing is: at one point there will be probably an entry in the "test" table with "number" 100, what means I will need 100 columns in the created table. Additionally I will save data from up to 20 years with a resolution of 15 minutes, so a huge amount of data. I wanted to make sure, that there will be not millions of indexes with "NULL" entry (test.number = 1 will have 99 empty columns in a table where test.number =100 is included... and that for each row!).
Or does that make no difference in the perfomance?

Comment: @Luke If you don't have rows/entries at a specific index you don't need to add a row for that index. If you have a test with possible `100` numbers, but only have a value for number `45` you only add a row `(theGeneratedId, 45, your_value)`.

Comment: I updated my question, as I think it wasn't completely clear, what I want to do. Maybe you can have another look? 
Or I am getting you wrong, that's possible as well.

Comment: @Luke You should add indices on the column which is used to group the entries together like the `testId` column. This way the database can use the index to fetch only the relevant data and not the whole table when you do a `SELECT ...... WHERE testId=42` query.